# Mysql.server start error

Tags: mysql

OS: Win 7
MySQL: 5.6.13

I set my PATH to the bin folder already.  When I'm in CMD and I type 'mysql', I can see that it's working.  However, when I type 'mysql.server start' into the command, it gives this error:

> 'mysql.server' is not reconigzed as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This is what I put in the PATH System Variable:

```
;H:\Tuts Plus\220\mysql-5.6.13-winx64\mysql-5.6.13-winx64\bin
```

Please help.  I'm trying doing a tutorial to learn how to program Python but this is blocking my progress.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a silly question, but did you restart your Windows after   modifying your System PATH?

Comment: `mysql.server` is not a valid command AFAIK. see [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html)

Comment: When I type "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld" into CMD, I get this error: TIMESTMAP with implicit DEFAULT value...

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 cases when windows throws this error.

1) the software is not installed
2) the software is installed but Windows can't find the executable

I assume you've used Windows Explorer to verify that the mySQL software
exists on your computer.  If not, please do.

You can check the PATH from the command line.  Just enter PATH.  If the mySQL directory isn't listed in what's printed in response, and you used the Windows Installer to install the software, you probably need to reinstall it.  The installer should have modified the PATH and, if it didn't, there may be other stuff it had trouble with too.  If you want to add the mySQL directory to the PATH yourself you can do it through 
Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables button.

Comment: Yes, I used the Windows installer.  I had to manually edit the PARTH to include the bin folder.  When I type PATH, it does show the correct path.

Comment: try invoking the file mysqld directly to start the server...not sure if mysql.server runs on Windows.

This should help

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/windows-start-command-line.html