# mysql.server: command not found

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-mint

I am new to Linux and mysql. I downloaded and installed mysql for linux as directed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

My OS is Linux Mint 17 and I installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** version of mysql.

I executed:

> `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.1.5-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb`

chose `mysql-5.6` and then executed:

> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install mysql-server
> sudo mysql_install_db

Now when I try to run `mysql.server`, it says:

> mysql.server: command not found

But when I executed `sudo service mysql start`, it says:

> * A MySQL Server is already started

Do I have to worry about `mysql.server` command not being found or should I just ignore it and move on?

This question is different from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758614/mysql-server-start-error) as it pertains to Windows OS.

Comment: what do you mean by `mysql.server` command? I don't know any such command exists. are you referring to `mysql` command? looks like you have a correctly installed MySQL server, start using it.

Comment: @bansi, sorry about that. Realized my mistake.

Comment: @bansi, I checked and `mysql.server` is a server startup script, my bad. This is the [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-server.html). Since my MySQL server is up and running, I won't worry about executing this script. Thanks

Comment: @bansi, should I add `[Closed]` to the question?

Comment: No need to close the question. This may be helpful to somebody having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if mysql is running use the following command:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Comment: I get the output as ` * MySQL Community Server 5.6.19 is running`. Thanks for the answer